# C# Split a List in Columns

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to split a List in C# and display the results in columns like this:

```
ID 1  ID 2
ID 3  ID 4
ID 5  ID 6
```

Instead of displaying them like this:

```
ID 1
ID 2
ID 3
ID 4
ID 5
ID 6
```

This is my list:

```
private List<ID> IDs = new List<ID>();
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
int chunkNumber = 1;
foreach (int[] chunk in Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Chunk(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Chunk {chunkNumber++}:");
    foreach (int item in chunk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {item}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Any help on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like a UI problem, not a `List<T>` problem.

Comment: @MickyD Yes, any help on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you mean to output _"Chunk"_ as you are doing in your `Console.WriteLine`?  Should that be _"ID"_?

Comment: I'm looking to display the ID in this case.

Answer (score 1):

just use Write instead of WriteLine

```
foreach (int item in chunk)
{
    Console.Write($"    {item}");
}
```

or this if you like it more

```
Console.Write($"    ID {item}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index by steps of 2 with a for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i += 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{IDs[i]}  {IDs[i+1]}");
}
```

This will only work if the list has an even number of elements. To be able to handle odd-length lists, try something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i += 2)
{
    if (i < IDs.Count - 1)
        Console.WriteLine($"{IDs[i]}  {IDs[i+1]}");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"{IDs[i]}");
}
```